# Optimize set and project operation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-java

An intermediate output of our aggregation pipeline is as follows:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "..." }, "requestId" : "REQ4", "scrips" : ["3553", "5647", "1234", "0007"], "matched" : [{ "settlement" : "9001" }, { "settlement" : "9002" }], "settled" : [{ "settlement" : "9001" }, { "settlement" : "9003" }] }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "..." }, "requestId" : "REQ5", "scrips" : ["3554", "3456"], "matched" : [{ "settlement" : "9003" }], "settled" : [{ "settlement" : "9001" }, { "settlement" : "9003" }] }
```

The ask is to print/return request(and scrips) for which `matched` is an exact subset of `settled`.
Expected output:

```
{ "requestId" : "REQ5", "scrips" : ["3554", "3456"] }
```

The following code seems to achieve it - is there a more efficient and concise way to achieve it?

```
        filters.add(Aggregates.project(
                Projections.fields(
                Projections.include("requestId","scrips"),
                Projections.computed("unmatched", 
                        Document.parse("{ $setDifference: 
                        ['$matched','$settled'] }")))));
        filters.add(Aggregates.match(Document.parse("{unmatched:{$eq:[]}}")));  
        filters.add(Aggregates.project(
                Projections.fields(
                Projections.excludeId(),
                Projections.include("requestId","scrips"))));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can also do it the following way:

```
List<Bson> filters = Arrays.asList(
                Aggregates.match(
                        Document.parse("{ $expr:{ $eq:[ { $size: { $setDifference:[ '$matched', '$settled' ] } }, 0 ] } }")),
                Aggregates.project(
                        Projections.fields(Projections.excludeId(), Projections.include("requestId", "scrips"))));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this aggregate query

```
Arrays.asList(
    Aggregates.project(
        Document.parse(
        `{ matchedIsSubsetOfSettled: { $setIsSubset: [ "$matched", "$settled"] },
           scrips: 1,
           requestId: 1}`
        )
    );
    Aggregates.match(
        Document.parse("{ matchedIsSubsetOfSettled: true }")
    ),
    Aggregates.project(
        Projections.fields(
            Projections.excludeId(),
            Projections.include("requestId", "scrips")
        )
    )
);
```